# Linq Include in Entity Framework make Web API show only some data in browser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The Web API was working perfectly until I used the linq `.Include` function, then the data starts to be portioned.

`Product` entity

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Media> Medias { get; set; }
}
```

`Media` entity

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Media
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] MediaContent { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [NotMapped]
    public string MediaUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return "http://localhost:7777/ImageStreamer/Index/" + Id.ToString();
        }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

`Category` entity:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This is the linq query

```
public List<Media> Find()
{
    return _context.Medias  
                   .Include(media => media.Product)
                   .ThenInclude(product => product.Category)
                   .ThenInclude(category => category.Products)
                   .Include(media => media.Product)
                   .ThenInclude(product => product.Medias).ToList();
}
```

This is the Web API result of media controller

```
[{"id":"c66d101f-57c8-4f03-b69f-227e75b84fd0","name":"thumb-1920-324689.jpg","productId":"d0dff87e-7280-4824-8fe1-5222450d7d20","product":{"id":"d0dff87e-7280-4824-8fe1-5222450d7d20","categoryId":"42809211-e087-4e2a-a3d1-7aa81f8693c9","name":"tv","price":433.0,"category":{"id":"42809211-e087-4e2a-a3d1-7aa81f8693c9","name":"level four","products":[
```

The problem is, calling any api controller retrieves data correctly, I checked it while debugging; I found all the results are right even the related data is retrieved correctly. But the data returned to the browser is only some of it,  not the complete set of data as shown in the above result.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i call api/media, the returned result is not complete in the browser even debugging shows all the data is retrieved correctly, please check the end of the json result above.

Comment: I'd expect your serializer is not working correctly, probably the max. string length was reached or there is an escape/unrecognized character

Comment: @DevilSuichiro: He's using the standard Web API serializer.  Serializers can handle arbitrary characters.

Comment: this is only happened after using the include linq function, before i was calling context.media.tolist() and every thing was fine. but i used include in the query to fetch related data, then the problem appears

Comment: This is happening becasue you are now using `include` which means the resultant string is lot bigger than previous one. Try increasing buffer size,